# C# equivalent of for statement

Tags: c#, vb.net-to-c#

The following statement is vb.net and I need the C# equivalent

```
For i As Integer = 0 To Me.ListBox2.Items.Count - 1
        Id = Me.ListBox2.Items(i).ToString
```

I have tried numerous things but no luck.

If I do

```
for (int x = listBox2.Items.Count - 1; x >= 0; x --)
id = listBox.Item(x).ToString()
```

But says *Non-invocable member 'List.Box.Items' cannot be used like a method*

Comment: Note that you've also changed the iteration order between the two samples - I can't see an obvious reason why you would do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use square brackets for the indexer in C#:

```
 id = listBox.Items[x].ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks now feeling a tad stupid for not trying []